# Duplicate class warning when running Android instrumentation test

Tags: android, android-studio, android-espresso, android-testing

When creating a new empty activity project in Android Studio (3.5) and running the generated instrumentation test I get the following warnings:

```
W/zygote: Found duplicate classes, falling back to extracting from APK : /data/app/com.example.myapplication.test-888XseHjUJwZJ8YXwEvomw==/base.apk
W/zygote: NOTE: This wastes RAM and hurts startup performance.
W/zygote: Found duplicated class when checking oat files: 'Ljunit/runner/BaseTestRunner;' in /data/app/com.example.myapplication.test-888XseHjUJwZJ8YXwEvomw==/base.apk and /system/framework/android.test.runner.jar
```

What causes them? Can they be avoided?

Comment: Are you able to run tests regardless of these warnings?  I have the same warnings and can't get my tests to run: `TestRunner: run started: 1 tests ... TestRunner: run finished: 0 tests, 0 failed, 0 ignored ` But if I clone https://github.com/wix/Detox/tree/master/examples/demo-react-native I'm able to run tests and don't see those warnings.

Comment: To answer my own clarification question, you can indeed run tests regardless of those warnings.  My issue was due to DetoxTest.java being in main instead of its own "androidTest" folder.

Answer (score 1):

first make sure you have the latest version of IDE, then **your IDE will tell you exactly what class is duplicated**. try to avoid using any of duplicated classes.