# "This wastes RAM and hurts startup performance" warning in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, debugging

I usually see these warning in debug console when I run my Flutter app. But the app works as expected and has no error. Anyone know why that happened and how to resolve that?

```
Found duplicate classes, falling back to extracting from APK : /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/000000ce/MapsDynamite.apk
Found duplicated class when checking oat files: 'Landroid/support/v4/app/RemoteActionCompatParcelizer;' in /data/app/com.buyhousing.online-24NDKGVlcoZl39sj6XxGIg==/base.apk and /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/000000ce/MapsDynamite.apk
Found duplicate classes, falling back to extracting from APK : /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/000000cd/GoogleCertificates.apk
Found duplicated class when checking oat files: 'Landroid/support/v4/app/RemoteActionCompatParcelizer;' in /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/000000cd/GoogleCertificates.apk and /data/app/com.buyhousing.online-24NDKGVlcoZl39sj6XxGIg==/base.apk
NOTE: This wastes RAM and hurts startup performance.
```

It says `This wastes RAM and hurts startup performance` so it seems to be important? I use Flutter SDK 2.8.1.

Here is the screenshoot  of the warning on the debug console, in case you would like to see it.

[image]

Update Feb 2 2022

When I removed widgets related to Google map, those warning doesn't appear. But when I re-added them, it appear again. I use google_maps_flutter (https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) and so I tested the example flutter project provided by the plugin (https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter/example) to check if the warning appear when I run that project or not, and found that those warning appear when I run that app, as well.

Comment: You can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55526657/10157127)